# Type Face / Fonts not loading correctly on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I'm working on a project and something odd is happening and I can't figure out why. I've uploaded a set of typefaces and create the css to call it as done on other projects before.

When I load the page on Firefox the fontfamily is not the one that it should be. Could someone please try to spot what the problem is.

Here is the development URL with the fontfamily working fine:
http://bgrgsummit.com/FrontEndDev/

Here is the production URL with the fontfamily not working on Firefox
http://bgrgsummit.com/code/web/

THanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are missing at the requested location - just check e.g. http://bgrgsummit.com/FrontEndDev/fonts/dtr-blackit-webfont.eot (working) vs http://bgrgsummit.com/code/web/fonts/dtr-blackit-webfont.eot (not found). Just checked this using the path of the font declared in the typeface.css.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reasons but it did the magic for me. 
To resolve the issue I added the following to my .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```